Latex error with begin
I have a problem: ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin
My PDFLatex code:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,upref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\newpage    
\thispagestyle {empty}
--> \section*{\textbf{First Section}} %Error is here
\begin{tabular}{l}
$\lambda_1$ \\
$\lambda_2$\\
\\ \\ \\ 
\end{tabular}
\thispagestyle {empty}
\end{document}


The document environment is missing and $ needs to be escaped if used outside of math mode. Once I fix these, your code compiles fine for me.

Are you absolutely sure that your file is encoded in  cp1251?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your codes fragments as complete small document, which we can test as it is. At this consider @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz comments.

Your new code compiles without error for me. Can you show your .log file?

For general code hygiene, plase get rid of the last four [4!] of the five instances of \.

even if your original document was coded as cp1251 it is not possible to post using that encoding here, all code fragments on this site are in UTF-8 (and so need no inputenc line)

Off-topic: You usually should not use something like \section*{\textbf{…}}. Instead configure \section to use the expected font, e.g., redefining \section or using a package like sectsty or titlesec or a configurable class like scrartcl or memoir.

the posted code runs with no error, please post an example that is related to the error that you are asking about.
